# Two children with the same key in React Native with Native Base

Tags: javascript, list, react-native, listitem, native-base

How I can fix the following error: Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

That is my List:

```
<List style={custom.PartList}>
     <FlatList extraData={this.state} data={this.state.data} keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor.bind(this)} renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)} />
</List>
```

That is my List Item:

```
   /* Render Item - Render One Row - Item - (Tool) */
    _renderItem({ item }) {
        const custom = styles(this.props);

        return (
            <View style={custom.PartView}>
                <ListItem style={custom.PartListItem} onPress={() => this._handleRead(item.tool_id, item.tool_name, item.tool_description, item.tool_count, item.tool_availability)}>
                    <Image style={custom.PartImage} source={require('@app/assets/images/tools.png')}/>
                    <Text style={custom.PartName}>{item.tool_name}</Text>
                </ListItem>
            </View>
        );
    }
    /* /Render Item - Render One Row - Item - (Tool)/ */
```

And that is my keyExtractor method:

```
/* Key Extractor Method - For Index Tools */
  _keyExtractor(index) {
      return index.toString();
  }
/* /Key Extractor Method - For Index Tools/ */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For FlatList Code

```
<List style={custom.PartList}>
     <FlatList extraData={this.state} data={this.state.data}
    keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
 renderItem={this._renderItem.bind(this)} />
</List>
```

Comment: That's work but when I have sub page of main page I get again the same erorr. And the strange is I do not have list in sub page. What is this?

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: But now i get another error: Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in the componentWillUnmount method.

Comment: Do you have a listener in your code? Did you implemented   componentWillUnmount()  ?

Comment: Yes. I have implemented componentDidMount, componentDidUpdate and componentWillUnmount.

Comment: Did you see that?

Comment: Hi, sorry the Imgur website is blocked in our work office network :( , ping me at my mail ahmed.bouhmid94@gmail.com

Comment: Can you see ur email?

Answer (score 1):

You're binding `this` to keyExtractor function, so it'll provide `this` object as a first parameter (where you refer it as `index`). Therefore the return value will always be the string presentation of Object (**= [Object object]**)

The simple solution is just to declare `keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}` without any binding.

Comment: If I declare i again have the same error. And this is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

For me it worked adding exactly like this:

```
<FlatList
    data={mySkills}
    keyExtractor={this.keyExtractor}
    renderItem={({item, index}) => <SkillCard key={index} skill={item} />}
  />
```